# Everything leads to "one" number

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

You get an invitation from an Institute of Mathematics and you are told if you can solve a simple puzzle you can be part of their elite institution.

You have to fill the blank.

$6 \rightarrow 6$,
$7 \rightarrow 11$,
$8 \rightarrow 3$,
$9 \rightarrow 13$,
$10 \rightarrow$ __

Can you get into the institute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the answer is

> **5?**

Because...

> these are numbers 6-10 in the integer sequence *Number of halving steps to reach 1 in ['3x+1' problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CollatzProblem.html)*:
>
>  0, 1, 5, 2, 4, **6, 11, 3, 13, 5,...**
>
>  [oeis elaborates](http://oeis.org/A006666): *The total number of **steps to reach 1** under the modified '3x+1' map: T := n -> n/2 if n is even, n -> (3n+1)/2 if n is odd.* [The bold part is probably what the title references.]

Comment: ...I hope I don't get much flak for this, but I barely know what I just wrote. :/

Comment: That was fast. Your answer is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be

> 0

By taking alternate numbers in sequence.
I.e 6-3 &

11-13-....